# WPF ScrollViewer is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview

I want to add scroll view to my program and I tried ScrollView control but that don't take effect. It's my first time dealing with scrolls please help me :).

My xaml Code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF695887">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="795">
            <Canvas Name="zemelapis" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                <Image Name="pav_kelias" />
                <Image Name="car1" />
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Because these 2 images is not fitting here I need a scroll for them. Maybe I should use ScrollBar?

My program example: https://gyazo.com/a4ba7e4d5004632e2229a87e686c4c09
, as you can see bottom image is not fitting in range of window.

Comment: What if you change the `Canvas` to a `Grid`, or some other type of control or setting a defined height on the `Canvas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified `Auto` as `Height` and `Width`. This implies that the `Canvas` will fill the height available to it.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Auto sizing behavior implies that the element will fill the height
>   available to it.

In this case the available height is the height of the `ScrollViewer`.

If you want the `Canvas` to be bigger, and hence the `ScrollViewer` to scroll, you should set a height on `Canvas` that is bigger than the height of `ScrollViewer`.

So, for example:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF695887">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="795">
            <Canvas Name="zemelapis" Height="1000" Width="Auto">
                <Image Name="pav_kelias" />
                <Image Name="car1" />
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your ScrollViewer to work easily, use a Grid instead of a Canvas:

```
<DockPanel Background="#FF695887">
        <ScrollViewer >
            <Grid Name="zemelapis">
                <Image Name="pav_kelias" Source="acteurs.png"/>
                <Image Name="car1" Source="public.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
```

As explain by Domysee, Canvas gives you total control of the layout. Grid however will automatically adjust its size depending on the content.

See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

Comment: not working that way I want. I need Canvas anyway cause I manipulate with coordinates like GetTop, GetLeft...